# Перетаскиваемые компоненты Blazor

Tags: drag-n-drop, blazor, drag

Хочу сделать TreeView/многоуровневое меню, в котором можно было бы перетаскивать один элемент на другой, меняя порядок/иерархию (особенно иерархию).

Создал компонент `SavedItemsList` с приблизительно следующим содержанием

```
@foreach (var item in Items.Where(it => it.Value.ParentId == ParentId))
{
    <li>
        <button id="Item_@item.Key" class="btn"
                @onclick="@(() => SetSelectionId.InvokeAsync(item.Key))">@item.Value.Name</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary"
                @onclick="@(() => EditItemById.InvokeAsync(item.Key))">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger"
                @onclick="@(() => OnRemoveItemById(item.Key))">Del</button>
        @if (TryGetChilds(item, out var childsDict))
        {
            <ul>
                <SavedItemsList
                    Items="@childsDict"
                    ParentId ="@item.Key"
                    RemoveItemById="@this.RemoveItemById"
                    EditItemById="@this.EditItemById"
                    SetSelectionId="@this.SetSelectionId"/>
            </ul>
        }
    </li>
}
```

+блок @code с описанными параметрами и делегатами событий.

Собственно вопрос: есть ли какой-то корректный способ в Blazor организовать возможность перетаскивать один элемент списка На другой элемент (выше/ниже, может с каким-то программным курсором как в браузерах вкладки имеют некие якоря, отображающие, куда упадёт вкладка, когда отпустишь её), чтобы менять иерархию этими перетаскиваниями?

К сожалению, даже особо не пойму куда гуглить. Гугление по перетаскиванию в Blazor дало 0 вариантов, если говорить о вебе в целом, то там скрипты js, ориентирующиеся на координаты...
Если это (с js и отслеживанием координат) единственный вариант, то вопрос будет заключаться в том:

1. как получить координаты текущих отображаемых элементов, чтобы размещать элемент в нужном месте;
2. неужели придется-таки прибегнуть к чистому js/jquery в Blazor?! Или есть какие-то нативные способы работы с канвасом blazor?

P.S. Если есть какие-то альтернативные варианты тому, который я пытаюсь найти, с удовольствием рассмотрю их.

P.P.S. Пока составлял вопрос, догуглился вот до такой штуки:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Но пока только пытаюсь разобраться здесь + хотелось бы обойтись нативными средствами Blazor/C#, если таковые имеются по сабжу.

P.P.P.S. Изначально писал вопрос о том, что рекурсивный вызов компонентов не работает, но оказалось, что работает, поэтому с ходу нашёлся следующий вопрос на том же примере кода =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока не уверен, что это 100% подходящее решение, но это единственная информация, которую удалось найти, и вроде бы её можно принять за решение:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425677/how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-in-blazor

P.S. Да, информация вместе со ссылкой в Upd принятого ответа — исчерпывающая. Когда реализую свой пример, то запощу (есть такое слово, я гуглил) результат.

**UPD:**

Я реализовал Drag'n'Drop в меру, необходимую в рамках моей задачи: построение иерархического списка элементов, с возможностью редактировать эту иерархию.

Условная модель:

```
/// <summary>
/// Элемент списка
/// </summary>
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


/// <summary>
/// Перетаскиваемый элемент
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TValue">Тип перетаскиваемого элемента</typeparam>
public class DraggableItem<TValue>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ctor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">Элемент</param>
    public DraggableItem(TValue item)
    {
        Item = item;
    }

    public TValue Item { get; set; }

    public bool IsDroppedToCorrectTarget { get; set; }
}
```

Условный родительский компонент *ShowItemsList*:

```
@page "/ShowItemsList"
        <h3>ItemsList</h3>
    <CascadingValue Value="this">
        <ul
                ondragover="event.preventDefault();"
                @ondragend="HandleDragEnd">
            <ItemsList
                Items="@Items"/>
        </ul>
    </CascadingValue>

@code {
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();

    public DraggableItem<Item> Dragging { get; set; }

    public void SetDraggingItem(Item item)
    {
        // Можно было и напрямую присваивать, но лучше инкапсулировать такие штуки, имхо
        // вдруг обработка нужна и всё такое
        Dragging = new DraggableItem<Item>(item);
    }
}
```

Условный компонент контейнера списка *ItemsList*:

```
@foreach (var item in Items.Where(x => x.ParentId == ParentId))
{
    <SavedItem 
        Item="@item"
        Items="@Items.Except(Items.Where(x => x.ParentId == ParentId)).ToList()" />
}

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public ShowItemsList Parent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Guid? ParentId { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
}
```

Далее будет нечто совсем страшное. По-крайней мере выглядит отстойно, особенно часть с разметкой мне не нравится, но как умеем...
Может и по факту некорректно написано, но выкладываю как разобрался в данный момент, и оно работает так, как я ожидаю.

Компонент *SavedItem*:

```
<li 
    ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('', event.target.id);">
        <button 
            draggable="true" 
            @ondrop="@((x) => HandleDrop(x, Item))"
            @ondragstart="@(() => HandleDragStart(Item))"
            id="item_@Item.Id" 
            class="btn" 
            title="item_@Item.Id">@Item.Name</button>
    @if (HasChilds(Item))
    {
        <ul
            ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
            <ItemsList
                Items="@Items"
                ParentId ="@Item.Id"/>
        </ul>
    }
</li>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public ShowItemsList Parent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Item Item { get; set; }

    private bool HasChilds(Item item)
    {
        return Items?.Any(it => item.Id == it.ParentId) ?? false;
    }

    private void HandleDragStart(Item item)
    {
        Parent.SetDraggingItem(item);
    }

    private void HandleDragEnd(Item item)
    {
        if (!Parent.Dragging.IsDroppedToCorrectTarget)
        {
            Parent.Dragging.Item.ParentId = null;
        }
    }

    private async Task HandleDrop(DragEventArgs args, Item item)
    {
        if (Parent.Dragging is null || item.Id == Parent.Dragging.Item.ParentId)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (item.ParentId == Parent.Dragging.Item.Id)
        {
            var errorMessage = $"Циклическая ссылка! Отрисовка прервана!\n" +
                               $"Элементы {item.Id} и {Parent.Dragging.Item.Id} являются родительскими друг для друга!\n";

            throw new Exception(errorMessage);
        }

        Parent.Dragging.Item.ParentId = item.Id;
        Parent.Dragging.IsDroppedToCorrectTarget = true;
    }
}
```

Возможно тег списка нужно в компонент списков перенести, буду потом разбираться. Суть вопроса этот код должен раскрывать +-полностью =)

Открыт для конструктивной критики, дополнений и исправлений.

P.S. Код "обфусцировал" на ходу прямо на сайте, поэтому могут быть какие-то косяки/не компилиться. Вряд ли будет проблемой для понимания сути.

P.P.S. Моё первое применение CascadingParameter, не ожидал, что придется к нему прибегнуть всё же. Хотя если хорошенько разобраться, то возможно, что через Callback'и можно было и обойтись без него. Я просто слизал этот приём по ссылке.